# Wörter mit Binnenmajuskeln

Tags: spelling

Das Binnen-I (z.B. in »StudentInnen«) hat sich als einer von mehreren Versuchen Deutsch geschlechtsneutraler zu machen, in breiten Bevölkerungsschichten bereits einigermaßen etabliert, davon soll hier nicht die Rede sein.

Aber bei der Durchsicht der vom Institut für deutsche Sprache in Mannheim im Jahr 2012 herausgegebenen [Grundformliste](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html) bin ich auf diese Wörter gestoßen, weil dieselben Wörter auch in normaler Schreibweise in derselben Liste stehen:

> GlücksSpirale
>   HypoVereinsbank
>   KompetenzCenter
>   RegionalExpress
>   StattPartei

<sub>Wieviele Wörter mit Binnenmajuskel tatsächlich in der Liste stehen, weiß ich noch nicht, weil mir die genannten Wörter bei einer Duplikatsprüfung ausgespuckt wurden, und ich noch nicht gezielt nach solchen Wörtern gesucht habe.</sub>

Die beiden ersten (*GlücksSpirale, HypoVereinsbank*) dürften eingetragene Wortmarken, also Eigennamen sein. Hier wundert mich weniger, dass die Begriffe so geschrieben existieren, sondern eher, dass diese Marken in der Grundformliste stehen, denn z.B. »McDonalds« und »Mercedes« fehlen in der Liste (während »McDonaldisierung« und »Dienstmercedes« aber vorhanden sind).

Aber *KompetenzCenter*, *RegionalExpress* und *StattPartei* sind, zumindest in genau dieser Schreibweise, keine Marken.

Es gibt bei den ÖBB und bei der DB jeweils eine Zuggattung namens »Regional-Express«, und in der Schweiz gibt es auch den »RegioExpress« (der aber nicht in der Grundwortliste steht), aber die genaue Schreibweise *RegionalExpress* kann ich nirgendwo finden.

Ähnlich ist es mit der *StattPartei*. In Deutschland gibt es eine politische Kleinpartei, die sich laut eigener Schreibung »STATT Partei« schreibt, und deren Wikipedia-Artikel mit »Statt Partei« übertitelt ist. Aber ich finde nirgendwo die genaue Schreibweise *StattPartei*.

Kompetenzcenter gibt es viele, aber auch hier finde ich keines, dass sich mit einem großen C mitten im Wort schreibt.

Mich würde nun interessieren:

- Sind diese Wörter (insbesondere *KompetenzCenter*, *RegionalExpress* und *StattPartei*) korrekt geschrieben?
- Ist es gerechtfertigt, diese Wörter zu den Grundwörtern zu zählen?

---

**Nachtrag**

In der oben erwähnten Liste habe zusätzlich noch diese beiden Wörter gefunden, doch diesmal nur in der hier dargestellten Variante mit Binnenmajuskeln (d.h.: *Intercityexpress* und *Javascript* stehen nicht in der Liste):

> InterCityExpress
>   JavaScript

Beim ICE scheint die Sache gleich zu liegen wie beim RE (also Eigenname), und auch JavaScript ist ein Eigenname, bzw. eine Marke. Interessant ist, dass der »*Intercityzug*« ganz ohne Binnenmajuskeln in der Liste steht.

Comment: Heißt das nicht *McDonald's*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ist es gerechtfertigt, diese Wörter zu den Grundwörtern zu zählen?

Ich würde "KompetenzCenter" und "StattPartei" definitiv als Eigennamen von Organisationen sehen.

> RegionalExpress

In dieser Schreibweise (mit großem "E") bezeichnet das Wort meines Erachtens ausschließlich ein bestimmtes Angebot einer Bahngesellschaft und ist daher ebenfalls ein Eigenname.

Wenn man das Wort nicht für dieses Angebot nutzen würde, müsste man es meines Erachtens mit kleinem "e" schreiben.

> Sind diese Wörter korrekt geschrieben?

Bei Eigennamen bestimmt der Namensgeber die korrekte Schreibweise. Eine "korrekte Rechtschreibung" gibt es dabei nicht.

Comment: Wikipedia sagt: Die ehemalige Schreibweise der Deutschen Bahn AG RegionalExpress, mit Binnenmajuskel, ist weiterhin eine beim Deutschen Patent- und Markenamt eingetragene Wortmarke.

Comment: Ich würde »KompetenzCenter« und »StattPartei« ja auch gerne als Eigennamen abtun, aber offenbar verwendet niemand diese Worte als Eigennamen, zumindest nicht in dieser Schreibweise. Kompetenzcenter gibt es wie Sand am Meer, aber ich konnte keines finden, dass sich ohne Bindestrich, aber mit großen C schreibt. Bei der »STATT Partei« ist es sogar noch klarer: Da kommt nur diese eine Organisation in Frage, und die zieht es vor, sich mit Deppenleerzeichen, also keineswegs mit einem Binnenmajuskel, zu schreiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich habe mal nach beiden Wörtern in Google gesucht: "StattPartei" in dieser Schreibweise habe ich nicht gefunden. In einem Text, den ich gefunden habe, in dem das Wort nachweislich nicht als Eigennamen verwendet wurde, war das "p" klein geschrieben. Das Wort "KompetenzCenter" habe ich immer nur in Texten gefunden, in denen die Betreiber selbst ihre Beratungsstellen so nennen - was man wiederum als Eigennamen werten kann. Ich gehe daher davon aus, dass beide Wörter keine echten deutschen Wörter sind.

Answer (score 0):

Der Unterschied zwischen Eigennamen und generischen Namen ist, wie die meisten Unterschiede in der Sprache, fließend und im Einzelfall oft umstritten.

Meine Stadtverwaltung ist zum Beispiel stolz auf ihr umfassendes Netz von "MetroBussen" und hat daher vor einiger Zeit auch all ihre anderen Produkte in "StadtBus", "EilBus", "SchnellBus" und sogar "NachtBus" umbenannt. Da dies alles Produkte des Verkehrsverbundes sind, kann man ihm wohl nicht das Recht absprechen, ihre Schreibweise zu bestimmen, d.h. sie als Eigennamen zu behandeln. Der Begriff "Nachtbus" ist aber, wenn überhaupt, dann nur ein sehr generischer Eigenname ("Ich fahre mit dem Nachtbus nach Hause...") und keineswegs vergleichbar mit "klassischen" Eigennamen wie "Peter" oder "Karstadt".

Allgemein haben Firmen ein großes Interese daran, Begriffe für ihre Produkte als Eigennamen behandeln zu lassen, weil das markenrechtliche Vorteile bringt. Der unaufhaltsame Abstieg von Marken zu generischen Begriffen (z.B. Tesa oder Q-Tip) wird von den Erfindern oft erbittert bekämpft. Da paßt es ins Bild, daß auch die zunehmend privatwirtschaftlich organisierten öffentlichen Dienstleister versuchen, sich einen wirtschaftlicheren Anstrich zu geben und das auch mit mühselig konstruierten Eigennamen betonen.

Comment: Der generische Markenname für Klebeband ist in Österreich übrigens ein anderer als in Deutschland. In Österreich heißt ein Klebeband »Tixo«. Tixo wurde ab ca. 1950 von der Firma Kores in Wien hergestellt und der Markenname steht auch im Österreichischen Wörterbuch. Kores stellte aber 1985 die Produktion von Tixo ein. Beiersdorf, der Hersteller von Tesa, hat die Markenrechte erworben, und seit 1985 kamen Tixo und Tesa jahrzehntelang aus derselben Fabrik. Und obwohl heute, wie ich glaube, kein Tixo mehr hergestellt wird, hält sich der Begriff noch immer als Gattungsname.

Comment: Tixo ist nach wie vor erhältlich. https://www.libro.at/tixo-lady-promotionpack-33m-15mm-1-rolle-gratis.html

Comment: @Ingmar: Danke. Ich hätte eigentlich nur auf meinen eigenen Schreibtisch schauen müssen, da steht nämlich genau der gleiche Abroller zu dem du einen Link gesetzt hast, nur ist meiner nicht rot sondern schwarz. Aber sowohl auf dem Abroller (den ich erst vor wenigen Monaten gekauft habe) als auch auf dem Klebeband steht groß »TIXO«.